# Match exact word in Linux

Tags: linux, grep

I am writing a shell script in which I looking for name of application.I am using grep to filter out application name.But along with application name I am also getting other application names containing that word.

Eg : grep notifications

Output : notifications

```
     notifications-ui
```

I get output of all applications containing word "notifications"
Is there any command in Linux to match only the word specified.

Any help on this will very helpful.

Thank You

Comment: Depends on what "only the word specified" means. Do you want to avoid characters before and after your word? Then, you could simply add whitespaces before and after your string to match.

Answer (score 0):

The man pages for grep will show you the light.

I believe the -x flag is what you are looking for.

> -x, --line-regexp
>   Select only those matches that exactly match the whole line. (-x is specified by POSIX .)

So try running:

```
    grep -x notifications
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but using -x I am not getting any output.

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU grep, you can try this

```
grep -E '(^| )notifications( |$)' FILE
```

Comment: `$ grep "\<notifications\>" <<< 'notifications-ui'`
`notifications-ui`

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams  yeah, my previous answer `grep "\<notifications\>" FILE`  cannot handle such cases. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Thanks for replying to the query. But I am looking for something like cf services | grep <<appname> . It should list services bind to only the app name specified.

Comment: you can feed the output of `cf services` to grep, like this `cf services | grep -E '(^| )notifications( |$)'`

Answer (score 0):

Try find command:

```
        find /path/notifications
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I am listing only names of application using cli and then using grep to filter it.